# Horizontal Scroll View/Page Control using Buttons

Tags: ios, swift

I've made a scroll view with page control using images (so far, so good)... I would like to use (3)buttons instead of images, and store the images in the button. So I can later create functions for each individual button. Having a hard time trying.

heres my code:

```
    import UIKit

class AddImovelVC: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollImageView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!


    var imageArray = [UIImage]()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollImageView.delegate = self

        imageArray = [UIImage(named:"0.png"), UIImage(named:"1.png"), UIImage(named:"2.png")] as! [UIImage]

        for i in 0..<imageArray.count{

            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.image = imageArray[i]

            imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill

            let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x:xPosition, y:0, width: self.scrollImageView.frame.width, height: self.scrollImageView.frame.width)

            scrollImageView.contentSize.width = scrollImageView.frame.width * CGFloat(i+1)

            scrollImageView.addSubview(imageView)

        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollImageView: UIScrollView) {
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(scrollImageView.contentOffset.x / CGFloat(375))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the UIImageView for UIButton inside the for loop, like this

```
let i = 0
let button = UIButton()
button.setImage(imageArray[i], for: [])
button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleToFill
let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
button.frame = CGRect(x:xPosition, y:0, width: self.scrollImageView.frame.width, height: self.scrollImageView.frame.width)
scrollImageView.contentSize.width = scrollImageView.frame.width * CGFloat(i+1)
scrollImageView.addSubview(button)
```

if you want to execute something when the user taps the button, just add `button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(nameOfYourFunction), for: .touchUpInside)` after creating the button.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIButton instead of UIImageView.

To set the image, use:

```
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
button.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
```

To retrieve the image, use:

```
button.currentImage
button.currentBackgroundImage
```